# How to combine partitions on an Windows XP laptop without a CD?

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

I have a small laptop (that doubles as a laptop - hp/compaq tc4400).  This laptop has no CD drive (or floppy for that matter).  I have 2 logical drives on it (C and D), but its the same physical drive.  I'd like to combine them.

All the partition managers I've run into need create either a CD or a floppy to boot into to actually perform the partitioning.  Since I have neither one, how can I combine the drives?

Comment: can it boot from usb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind.  EASEUS Partition app actually did the trick without having to boot from CDs or anything else.  It did require a restart, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

If your machine can boot from a usb drive, you can [create a bootable usb flash drive](http://www.google.com/search?q=create+usb+flash+drive+boot+disk).

To check if your BIOS will boot from USB, shut down the machine, and plug in the usb drive. Next, power on the machine and access the boot order menu. Finally, select the USB drive, if you can.

Many newer machines offer a "boot once" boot menu. So far, in my experience (Thinkpad T40 and T41, Dell D600 and D820) those machines all supported booting from USB.

For an older machine, I had to look in a secondary boot order menu. The first screen listed things like "Hard Drive", "CD", and "Floppy", but the second menu listed specific hard disks installed on my system - Channel 0 Master, Channel 0 Slave, and the USB when it was plugged in.